# How to send Video feed frames to a ThingsBoard widget, without requesting them from a local server?

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, iot, thingsboard

I've been searching for sending my local video feed from a Rasberry PI to a ThingsBoard Widget, the typical solution would be to expose the feeding device via port forwarding or VPN to be accessed from outside my network, then I would be able to request video frames from a typical image or video or iframe element with the aid of javascript.

but my need is a little bit complex, I want to send the video feed frames to a things board widget so I could have the video feed without the hassle of the port forwarding and the network stuff. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible other than what you suggested and make the feed available externally and pull into an iFrame in an HTML widget.  It would require a constantly connected feed to run through the Rule Engine from the device and it is not built that way.

What you could do depending on your requirements is have it send still frames from the camera in base64 every time it polls?